# Why the identity specification gives false results SQL Server (asp net)

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

The identity specification starts from the last number +1 even I have deleted all rows, it never starts from 1.

[image: The REsult]

[image]

Comment: why you say false result? That is the exact behaviour is supose to work. Your indentity doesnt need to be consecutive. Only need to be unique.

Comment: I want it starts from "1" .

Comment: If you *care* about the numeric value of `identity` columns, you're misusing them. You should treat them as opaque blobs that happen to fit inside numeric columns.

Comment: **Works as designed and documented** .....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you delete rows from your table the identity value is not reset. You need to either truncate the table (which will reset the identity) or RESEED the identity.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176057.aspx

Answer (score 0):

The identity spec isn't designed to restart from 1 after you do DELETE operations on a table.  You have to TRUNCATE TABLE to reset to 1.

Comment: You can reseed also. Truncate is not the only way to reset it. :D

Answer (score 0):

If you want to start the first number after deleting all items, you need to reset the seed.

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176057.aspx

```
DBCC CHECKIDENT ('[Table]', RESEED, 0);
GO
```